# Is Publisher Confirms active by default when using MassTransit?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a simple question, but I can't find evidence on the internet.

I'm connecting to `RabbitMQ` with `MassTransit`, and I just wanted to know if [Consumer Acknowledgements and Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) is **active** by default if a connection has been made to the broker using `MassTansit`?

If **active** by default: Where can I find evidence about this?

If **not active** by default: How can I enable these functionalities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PublisherConfirmation is active by default, and always has been that way. This means that a call to Publish, when awaited, will not complete until the message is confirmed by the broker (ack'd).

Consumers do not `ack` messages until they are processed by the consumer. If the consumer completes, the `ack` removes the message. If an exception was thrown, the message is moved to the `_error` queue and a `Fault<T>` is published.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Chris. I couldn't find any documentation as evidence unfortunately. Do you also know how I can disable these functionalities using MassTransit?

Comment: Yes, it's configurable on the host: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/Configuration/IRabbitMqHostConfigurator.cs#L24

Comment: And consumer acknowledgements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about consumer acknowledgements, I explained how consumers work in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, is there also a toggle for consumer acks? Can I disable an enable it using MassTransit?

Comment: No, nor would you need to when using MassTransit. It manages it all for you.